# Como fazer um Popup que so grava informacao no cookie ou qualquer coisa e exibe somente uma vez na pagina inicial do site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Tenho um site de entretenimento adulto e preciso fazer um termo de 18 anos para entrar no site antes... Sera exibido uma tela confirmando a idade e tal da pessoa para ela clicar em ok caso for maior. Mas o código jquery não executa mais para o usuário. alguém poderia me ajudar?
A parte do desing e do javascript já estão prontas:

## JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a.accept_legal_majority').click(function(){
        jQuery('#cp_overlay').remove();
        jQuery('#legal_majority').remove();
        jQuery.get('https://www.site.com.br/salvar', function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

## HTML:

```
<div id="cp_overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
<div id="legal_majority">
  <div class="legal_majority_content">
    <div class="header_warning">


      <div class="title txt-center">
        <h1 style="font-size:22px;"><span class="color-rejected">Aviso: </span>Este website é apenas para adultos!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terms">
      <a class="bg-hover-free btn_submit accept_legal_majority">Eu aceito</a>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="legal_majority_out txt-center btn-edit">Não Tenho 18 anos, Desejo Sair</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a linguagem back-end? Recomendaria sessões.

Comment: Codeigniter, mas neste caso posso usar o Php ou html simples mesmo

Comment: Qual versão do Codeigniter? O 3?

Comment: Sim, o 3. Exatamente,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução para essa aplicação :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function setCookie(name, value, days) {
       if (days) {
           var date = new Date();
           date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
           var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
       } else var expires = "";
       document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
   }

   function getCookie(name) {
       var nameEQ = name + "=";
       var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
       for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
           var c = ca[i];
           while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
           if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
       }
       return null;
   }

   $(document).ready(function () {

       var box = getCookie('janela_modal');

       if (box == null) {
           launchWindow('#dialog1');
           $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#mask').hide();
               $('.window').hide();
           });
           setCookie('janela_modal', 'visitou', 1);
       }
   });

   function launchWindow(id) {
       var maskHeight = $(document).height();
       var maskWidth = $(window).width();
       $('#mask').css({
           'width': maskWidth,
           'height': maskHeight
       });
       $('#mask').fadeIn(0);
       $('#mask').fadeTo("fast", 0.8);
       var winH = $(window).height();
       var winW = $(window).width();
       $(id).css('top', winH / 2 - $(id).height());
       $(id).css('left', winW / 2 - $(id).width() / 2);
       $(id).fadeIn(0);
   }
</script>
</head>


<div id="cp_overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
<div id="legal_majority">
  <div class="legal_majority_content">
    <div class="header_warning">


      <div class="title txt-center">
        <h1 style="font-size:22px;"><span class="color-rejected">Aviso: </span>Este website é apenas para adultos!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="terms">
      <a class="bg-hover-free btn_submit accept_legal_majority">Eu aceito</a>
    </div>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="legal_majority_out txt-center btn-edit">Não Tenho 18 anos, Desejo Sair</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show Bruno Roberto Parabéns!

Comment: Valeu @RafaelSalomão

Answer (score 5):

No back-end pode usar `session_start();` e definir uma variavel, algo como:

**aceitar.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['aceito'] = 1;
```

Se for CodeIgniter 3:

```
 $this->load->library('session');
 $this->session->aceito = 1;
```

No JS assim:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('a.accept_legal_majority').click(function(){
        jQuery('#cp_overlay').remove();
        jQuery('#legal_majority').remove();
        jQuery.get('aceitar.php', function(data){
            //console.log(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Ou defina a rota acaso seja CI

> É importante notar que o session deve vir antes de qualquer `echo`, `print`, ou html, isto porque o session usa os headers na resposta HTTP

Na pagina inicial faça isto (versão resumida):

```
<?php $this->load->library('session'); ?>
<html>

...

<?php
if (!$this->session->aceito) {
?>
<div id="cp_overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
<div id="legal_majority">
    <div class="legal_majority_content">
        <div class="header_warning">
            <figure class="logo">

            </figure>

            <div class="title txt-center">
                <h1 style="font-size:22px;"><span class="color-rejected">Aviso: </span>Este website é apenas para adultos!</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="terms">
            <p class="txt-center">Por favor leia o seguinte texto antes de entrar no site lascivacam.com:</p>
            <div class="contract">
                <p style="color:#000;">
    Este website contém cont ...
    .... enho 18 anos, Desejo Sair</a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Se a pagina do popup não for a principal pode optar por um redirecionamento:

```
<?php

$this->load->library('session');
if (!$this->session->aceito) {
?>

<div id="cp_overlay" style="opacity:0.9;"></div>
...
</div>
<?php
} else {
?>
<script>window.location="paginaprincipaldepoisdoaceitar.php";</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Isso Guilherme certissímo !! =P

Comment: a pagina do popup e a principal, mas tipo ele não ta conseguindo recuperar a session, para saber o q foi gravado.

Comment: @BrunoRoberto vou testar aqui e assim que conseguir lhe aviso.

Comment: E porque a minha CI e um pouco complexa, ela não e padrão como geralmente e a Ci ... ela tem subpastas com views pra cada tipo de aplicação.

Comment: Cokiee n seria melhor n deixo ele expirar pro usuario ... eu axo q seria bem melhor.

Comment: @BrunoRoberto o session tem que vir antes de qualquer echo, print ou html, tem que ficar no topo de tudo, se não ele não funciona, obs: os cookies expiram também e se não tiver data pra expirar eles são removido quando o navegador é fechado, o que é a mesma coisa do session.

Comment: no caso como eu fiz, esta funcionando do modo certinho que precisava.

Comment: @BrunoRoberto não estou falando disso, estou falando do comportamento geral, não é porque parece que funciona que não vai falhar, PS: o session não funcionou pra ti porque o `$this->load->library('session')` deveria estar no topo do documento, antes de echo, print e do `<html>`

Comment: A sim, desculpa hahaha!

Comment: Foi você quem negativou @BrunoRoberto ? Tem algum motivo para isto?

Comment: `LocalStorage` não seria mais fácil?

Comment: @MaxRogério entre fácil e dificil depende da intimidade da pessoal com front-end e back-end, ele informou que usa CI3 eu dei um exemplo que é em um ambiente que ele esta acostumado, qualquer forma é fácil para quem esta acostumado com um ambiente.

Answer (score 1):

Não aconselho cookies para isso é melhor utilizar sessão assim que o usuário entrar você inicia uma sessão e cria uma variável aonde fica armazenado que ele leu a mensagem em seguida sempre que ele retornar a index você verifica a variável em sessão para não exibir novamente a mesma mensagem.

Dá uma lida nisso aqui :

[Trabalhando com Sessões](https://blog.vilourenco.com.br/php-trabalhando-com-sessions/)

vai ajudar a montar o script

Abraços.

Comment: Isto ficaria melhor como comentário.

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta acima.

Comment: Eu axo q ter isso como Session não seria boa ideia sendo que meu codigo e trabalhado em codeigniter () ele já tem sessions, e o botão na verdade e um link... e não um button com submit

Comment: nem todos os navegadores utilizam de cookies e muitos deles tem os cookies desativados portanto para esse quadro ira se repetir por isso aconselhei sessão. Se já existe uma sessão definida em seu script basta adicionar uma variavel a sessão para montar o que expliquei acima!

Comment: De onde tirou que não aceita cookies? Sessão é cookie, como não aceitaria? Creio que esteja fazendo confusão, o que alguns navegadores não aceitam é a interação com controle HTTPS de cookies ou o acesso no cliente-side e isto depende muito, mas no back-end não tem disto não.

Comment: Basta o usúario desativar os cookies e pronto não funciona mais. Para isso cookie é uma furada! Eu uso o memcached para salvar dados assim! Além disso existem poucos navegadores que não tem suporte a cookie. cito navegadores nativos de celular antigo e televisores. Para ler sobre session sem cookies pode seguir isso : 
https://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Session_no_Php_sem_a_utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Cookies

Comment: Sim, mas se desabilitar cookies ou o navegador não suportar a sessão também não funcionaria, a unica maneira de resolver seria usando sessionStorage ou localStorage ou até mesmo baseado em IP que pode ser pior ainda. Se o navegador da pessoa não funciona com cookies o usuário nem conseguiria acessar sites como facebook ;)

Comment: REFERÊNCIA
http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.session.php 
"Um visitante acessando o seu web site ganha um identificador único, o assim chamado id de sessão. Este é salvo em um cookie do lado do usuário ou propagado via URL."

Entretanto, o Php também disponibiliza formas alternativas(id propagado via URL) de salvar o ID da sessão sem a utilização de cookies. =P

Comment: @RafaelSalomão parece quase uma boa, mas se o visitante sair e voltar não vai funcionar, entende?

Comment: Ahh sim tem razão! Certissímo como no seu post!

Comment: No caso do visitante sair e voltar seja ele unico , não tem problema, agora n pode e so funcionar pra um cada usuario e responsavel pelo seu pc.

Comment: Consegui resolver com esse problema aqui vou da a resposta la em cima.

Answer (score 1):

Podes tentar algo mais simples utilizando um `Modal` em sua view e o seguinte código no seu *Controller*

`$this->session->set_flashdata('alert', 'Sua mensagem');`

*view:*

```
<h3 style="color:red;"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('alert');?></h3>
```

e adicione os botoes de aceitar ou recusar redirecionando para onde quiser